Streamlit Unity WebGL
I want to publish the games I make on the websites I create. I put the WebGL output of the game in a folder called WebGL. I want to find the path of the index.html in Streamlit  and run the game. What Chatgpt said didn't work. Can anyone help?
import streamlit as st
import streamlit.components.v1 as components
import os

webgl_folder = "WebGL"
html_file_path = os.path.join(webgl_folder, "index.html")
with open(html_file_path, "r") as f:
    html_content = f.read()
components.html(html_content, height=600)

